# How can I use a file or text with footer-html? I'm using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: html, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm using wkhtmltopdf to convert an html template into a pdf, and I want to use some html as a footer, but as far as I can tell I have to make the html a webpage, which means it would be visible to the public. So I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to use a string or a file with footer-html?
2. If not, is there any way to prevent the footer webpage from being visible to the public? I'm using flask to make my website.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not want anyone to see the footer tag?

A `<footer>` element typically contains:

- authorship information
- copyright information
- contact information
- sitemap
- back to top links
- related documents

Also, no one can see your html unless you publish it.

If this does not answer your question, consider to edit it with a more clear question.

If you really want to hide it you can go to the link below ^^

[W3schools Example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using wkhtmltopdf to convert an html page to a pdf. I want a footer at the bottom of each page, and wkhtmltopdf has a footer option called footer-html.